# ANOVAS and Planned Comparisons

Tags: self-study, planned-comparisons-test

I'm fairly new to stats and we have been asked to conduct our own one way ANOVA's for class.

Our first hypothesis is that gender will effect exercise. Our second is more one tailed, Men will participate in exercise more than women. Therefore we have been told to carry out a planned comparison if our results for the first hypothesis are significant. However is this really needed if there are only two groups? Will the ANOVA not already tell us that men exercise more if the test is significant and we look at the means?

Answer (score 0):

For two groups and one dependent variable, an ANOVA is equivalent to a t-test of the two groups. Saying you should conduct an ANOVA before doing the between-groups comparison is therefore nonsensical in this case. There is only one comparison to make: men's exercise behavior vs. women's exercise behavior.